# Efficiently select rows from 2 datatables matching sum for a column

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have 2 datatables :

1. Payables: contains a set of Invoices which I have to Pay. ( InvNo-Amount )
2. Receivables: contains a set of Invoices which I have to Receive. ( InvNo-Amount )

I have to create a process wherein I have to select **maximum rows** from both the tables such that their sum is equal.

**Example:**

```
Payables        Receivables
--------        -----------
INV1 120        ABC1 100
INV2  50        ABC2 30
INV3  80        ABC3 20
INV4  30        ABC4 70
```

I can create a combination of `(INV1 + INV2 + INV4 = 200) & (ABC1 +  ABC2 + ABC4 = 200)` so that both match.

The *idea* which I have for implementing is :

1. Find Invoices with same amount from both tables & select them.
2. Find item with maximum amount from either table. 
   Try to match this amount by selecting rows (one or many) from other table.

But I know this logic will fail at some point of time to match maximum invoices. I cannot recollect the technical name for such operations.
Looking for starters either as algorithm or pseudo code or approach.

Comment: Inv3/xInv3 are not relevant? Do you need to compare the maximum rows only or do you want to find the highest sum-values with have a match in the other table?

Comment: no. they are different

Comment: idea is to match maximum amount from both sides..

Comment: "match maximum amount" means that you only want to compare the maximum rows or that you want to find the highest matching values?

Comment: @TimSchmelter From the eg, the max amount I could match is 200, so i am searching for a way to neutralise those invoices & knock off amount. My goal is maximum amount should be knocked off from them.

Comment: i don't know what "knock off" means in this context. Maybe it would help if you would provide a more meaningful sample with more rows than only one.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have edited the question..

Comment: So you want to find the maximum row of `Payables`, then search the row in `Receivables` with the same value. After that you want to find the maximum row of `Receivables`, then  search the row in `Payables` with the same value. If you have two matches you want to take the maximum value of both?

Comment: I want to pick rows from payables & receivables such that their sum of amount match.

Comment: Better example of input and output is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

What I would do is to generate all the sums that you can get with payables, then all the sums you can get with receivables and then look where they overlap and take the largest value.

Something like this:

```
def knapsack(items) {
  sums = {0: null}
  for item in items:
     for sum, last_item in sum:
       // Skip if you've already used item or the you can get the sum some other way.
       if last_item == item or sum + item.value in sums: continue
       else:
         sums[sum+item.value] = item          
  return sums

payable_sums = knapsack(payables)
receivable_sums = knapsack(receivables)
for sum, item in payable_sums:
   if sum in receivable_sums:
      print "Success, you can get ", sum, " on both sides."
```

If you need to get the actual items just use the values in the maps to identify the last item, subtract the value of the item and repeat for the remaining sum until you reach 0.

The algorithm will always give you a result (at least 0 on both sides).

Comment: I took your approach of generating all possible sum values (using combinations) for both the sets, & find the max value which exists in both.

Answer (score 1):

This problem looks very similar to the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

The Payables can be represented as negative values, and the Receivables as positive, and then you need to find a non empty set that sums 0.

If you want to do the [knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) variation, you can implement a very efficient solution to the knapsack problem with [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), for each table separately, and then query the resulting matrix for sizes of the knapsack that have the same value for payables and receivables.